# Angular 2 - Identifier is not defined

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript

I've weird problem, my Visual Studio Code marks me an error but there is no error and everything is working well. What's wrong?

[image]

```
export class HomeComponent {
  public ElectronicList = [];
  public LaptopList = [];
  public constructor(
    private electronic: DatabaseService,
    private laptop: DatabaseService
  ) {
    this.electronic
      .getElectronicList()
      .subscribe((data: Response) => (this.ElectronicList = data.json()));

    this.laptop
      .getLaptopList()
      .subscribe((data: Response) => (this.LaptopList = data.json()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Common problem, see [here](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/149)

Comment: ohh, so it's the visual studio code problem then? waiting for update then, thanks !

Comment: Yep, you are welcome :)

Comment: Can we see the definition of `ElectronicList`?

Comment: According to the [VSCode issue](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/149), you can get rid of the problem by defining a type for the items in `ElectronicList`, instead of having items of type `any`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the editor isn't able to find the component or something like that (unless your component is called 'anonymous'). Have you tried cleaning your code?

Comment: yeah it's clean, i have many others projects some created by others ppl and it's the same everywhere,

Comment: Don't use answer when you need to comment !

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment.